# if date is current date only then it shows the task

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

This logic is not working its shows me no task what ever date i entered

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector} from 'react-redux';

export default function Today() {
    const tasks = useSelector(state => state.tasks);
    const newDate= new Date();
    const currentDate = newDate.getDate();


 return(


        <div>

            {Object.values(tasks).map((task, index) => (

                <ul>
                    <li
                        key={index.toString()}
                        index={index}


                        style={{
                            textDecoration: !task.completed ? 'inherit' : 'line-through'
                        }}
                    >
```

> here i put the currentDate equals to addedAt but its not working always show me Notask. 
>   what should i do here so its shows me tasks with currentDate only and if no task in todays date then it shows notask

```
                  {task.currentDate === task.addedAt ? 
                        <div>
                            <h3>{task.text}</h3> 
                            <p>{task.addedAt.toString()}</p> 

                        </div>
                        :
                        <div>
                        <p>No Task</p>
                        </div>
                        }
                    </li>
                    {task.task}

                </ul>

            ))}
            </div>


    )           
  }
```

Comment: Maybe its because you are using task.currentDate indeed currentDate.

Comment: we need more detailed code to help you out, i prefer that you a codesandbox showing you problem.

Comment: @adel i am sorry i am not using  codesandbox you can check  git@github.com:jzebgul/mytodo.git

Comment: `date.getDate()` will only return the current day, so for `task.addedAt` i cant tell how its defined as full date or day...

Comment: addedAt define full date with time i want compare the day if it is current day then it shows the task in today

Answer (score 1):

if `task.addedAt` is a `Date` object, you can use `isToday` function I wrote

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

/**
 * @param {Date} date
 */
function isToday(date) {
   var currentDate = new Date()
  try {
    return (
      date.getFullYear() === currentDate.getFullYear() &&
      date.getMonth() === currentDate.getMonth() &&
      date.getDate() === currentDate.getDate()
    )
  } catch {}
  return false;
}

export default function Today() {
  const tasks = useSelector(state => state.tasks)

  var count = 0
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.values(tasks).map((task, index) => {
          var isTodayTask = isToday(task.addedAt)
          if (isTodayTask) {
            count++
          }
          return (
            <ul>
              <li
                key={index.toString()}
                index={index}
                style={{
                  textDecoration: !task.completed ? 'inherit' : 'line-through',
                }}
              >
                {isTodayTask ? (
                  <div>
                    <h3>{task.text}</h3>
                    <p>{task.addedAt.toString()}</p>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <div>
                    <p>No Task</p>
                  </div>
                )}
              </li>
              {task.task}
            </ul>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: how can i get the length of todays task i am doing {Object.values(tasks).length} but gettin the length of all task i only want the length of today tasks

Comment: when and where do you need the count of today-tasks?if you need it in `render` function and after `map` you can use a counter after the condition.

Comment: yes after the map i want to see the count of todays Tasks